# Is there any example of using ThreeNodes.js as a library?

Tags: javascript, graph, nodes

I found this nice library/project: [ThreeNodes](https://github.com/idflood/ThreeNodes.js) ([demo](http://idflood.github.com/ThreeNodes.js/public/index.html#example/postprocessing1.json)).

I wonder if any one could provide an example of using it from js (not CofeeScript) for creating a simle page with 3 costume connected nodes on it (for example costume component box with string and number input feilds and 2 outputs coming into standart base components string and number)?

Answer (score 0):

ThreeNodes let's you export code as JS: http://idflood.github.com/ThreeNodes.js/public/code_export_example.html